# Как выполнить скрипт для динамически сформированного каталога?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется каталог товаров

```
<div cass="catalog">
    <div class="product">
      Содержимое продукта 1
      цена
      - 1 +
      добавить в корзину
    </div>
    <div class="product">
      Содержимое продукта 2
      цена
      - 1 +
      добавить в корзину
    </div>
</div>
```

Как мне выполнять js-скрипт, например на увеличивание количества товара (+ -), чтобы он выполнялся только для одного товара? Сейчас выполняется для всех
Прилагаю код:

```
    $('.count-block__minus').click(function(){
     var price = getNumber($('#tovar_price').val());
     var count = getNumber($('#tovar_count').val());
     count--;
     if (count > 0) {
        $('#tovar_total').val(count*price);
        $('#tovar_count').val(count);
        $('#count').val(count);
        $('.tovar__price span').text(count*price);
     }
     });

    $('.count-block__plus').click(function(){
     var price = getNumber($('#tovar_price').val());
     var count = getNumber($('#tovar_count').val());

     count++;
     $('#tovar_total').val(hrPrice(count*price));
     $('#tovar_count').val(count);
     $('#count').val(count);
     $('.tovar__price span').text(hrPrice(count*price));
    });
```

Вот код html одного товара

```
 <div class="food_info" id="[[+id]]">
                <h3>[[+pagetitle]]</h3>
                <div class="discr">
                    [[+content]]  
                </div>
                <form method="post" class="ms2_form tovar__form" id="tovar__form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" id="tovar_price" value="[[+price]]">
                    <input type="hidden" name="total_price" id="tovar_total" value="[[+price]]">

                    <div class="price tovar__price"> <span>[[+price]]</span> [[%ms2_frontend_currency]]</div>
                    <div class="weight">Вес: [[+weight]]</div>
                    <div class="count-block">
                        <span class="count-block__minus" id="[[+id]]">-</span>
                        <input type="text" name="count" id="count" value="1" disabled="disabled">
                        <span class="count-block__plus" id="[[+id]]">+</span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form method="post" class="ms2_form" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="[[+id]]">
                    <input type="hidden" name="count" id="tovar_count" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="options" value="[]">
                    <!--button class="btn but add_to_order" type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add">Заказать</button-->
                    <button class="btn but" type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" style="border: none;">Заказать</button>
                    <!--button class="mdl-wrn btn but" type="submit" style="border: none;">Заказать</button-->
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

На основе предоставленной информации можно дать только общий ответ, обрабатывая клики по -/+ используйте `$(this).closest('.product')`, таким образом вы получите ближайший элемент с классом `product` при проходе по DOM-дереву от текущего элемента "вверх", дальше делайте с ним что душе угодно.

Вы, скорее всего, используете свой скрипт для всех элементов выбранных селектором `$('.product')`.

Пример:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
var id = $(this).closest('.product').attr('id');
console.log(`id продукта: ${id}`);
});
```

```css
.product{
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div cass="catalog">
    <div class="product" id="pepe">
      Продукт 1
      <button>Click!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="keke">
       Продукт 2
       <button>Click!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: приложил код, задумка ясна, но не хватает опыта внедрить(

Comment: @ВикторТимошков приложите тогда уж пример html для пары товаров

Comment: Приложил, добавил id, к plus и minus и попытался изменить как-то так $(this).closest('.count-block__minus').attr('id').click(function(), но это неправильно